# Error while uploading file to Sharepoint 2007 library via HTTP, file is too big?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, webclient

I have a Sharepoint 2007 document library I wish to upload a document into.

I am using the System.Net.WebClient class to do so, using the UploadFile() method.

I can upload 90% of the files I have, but the bigger ones are having trouble. I am getting an exception thrown, saying `"Unable to write data to the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host."`

The code:

```
var client = new WebClient();
client.UploadFile(destination, "PUT", source);
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

See if changing the following settings as suggested helps.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/925083